# Probability of union sets in conditional form

Tags: probability

We know how to calculate probability of union of sets [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability):

$$
P\Bigg(\bigcup^n_{i=1} A_i \Bigg) = \sum^n_{i=1}P\Big(A_i\Big)-\sum_{i<j}P\Big(A_i\cap A_j\Big)+\sum_{i<j<k}P\Big(A_i\cap A_j \cap A_k\Big)- ... +(-1)^{n-1}P\Big(\bigcap^n_{i=1}A_i\Big)
$$

I think we can wrote $P\big(\bigcup^n_{i=1} A_i | B \big)$ as below: (see "$|B$")

$$
P\Bigg(\bigcup^n_{i=1} A_i|B\Bigg) = \sum^n_{i=1}P\Big(A_i|B\Big)-\sum_{i<j}P\Big(A_i\cap A_j|B\Big)+\sum_{i<j<k}P\Big(A_i\cap A_j \cap A_k|B\Big)- ... +(-1)^{n-1}P\Big(\bigcap^n_{i=1}A_i|B\Big)
$$

Is above equation correct?

---

I proofed it for $n=2$:

$$
P\Big(A_1\cup A_2|B\Big)={P\Big((A_1\cup A_2)\cap B\Big)\over P(B)}={P\Big((A_1\cap B)\cup(A_2\cap B)\Big) \over P(B)}={P(A_1\cap B)+P(A_2\cap B)-P(A_1\cap A_2\cap B)\over P(B)}={P(A_1\cap B)\over P(B)}+{P(A_2\cap B)\over P(B)}-{P(A_1\cap A_2\cap B)\over P(B)}=P(A_1|B)+P(A_2|B)-P(A_1\cap A_2|B)=\sum^2_{i=1}P\Big(A_i|B\Big)-\sum_{i<j}P\Big(A_i\cap A_j|B\Big)
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. More generally speaking, in any general theorem about probabilities, you can introduce the same condition in all probabilities and the result is again a theorem, since the probabilities under a given condition themselves form a probability distribution. In effect, you're simply reasoning about how the world would look to you if you happened to know $B$.